# extjs hidden panel flicker when slide in on show

Tags: extjs, show, hidden, slide, flicker

I need to show a panel on a click event. The panel needs to slide into view on show and it needs to be anchored to the button once shown (the one that has the click event).

The panel config (helpPanel) is as follows:

```
{
    xtype: 'container',
    autoScroll: true,
    hidden: true,
    floating: true,
    shadow: false,
    listeners: {
        show: function(panel) {
            panel.el.slideIn('r', {
                easing: 'easeOut',
                duration: 500
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The panel is shown in the button's click event handler:

```
helpPanel.showBy(helpButton, 'tr-br');
```

It works fine, except there is a quick / small flicker before the panel is shown. A bit like the panel is shown and then it is hidden before sliding into the view again.

Is this the right way to implement a slide-in show?

Thank you

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cs2014/nwvahc60/

Answer (score 0):

You can show the panel off-screen and then slide it in with [animate](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-animate) method.

Comment: I did look at that but I struggled with (a) anchoring the panel to the button and (b) sliding